# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game, where I run my app once and I get this type error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here is the image:

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SOr5.png)

> Build Phases
>   [My Build Phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIxu7.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of exceptions, no one can search for this. Edit your question and add the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using latest Xcode remove the library `libc++abi.dylib` from build phase and add `libc++abi.tbd`

Hopes this will fix the issue.

Comment: I don't see no libc++abi.dylib in build phases. is it in target dependencies?

Comment: Then add libc++abi.tbd, under **Link Binary With Libraries**, And check issue is fixed. Also check if you are using any other third party frameworks is all up to date.

Comment: How do I do this @Arasuvel?  I'm not familiar with xCode at all.  I'm building an Ionic 4 application and after a bunch of errors with cocoapods I removed the xCode project file then readded and it builds successfully in Visual Studio Code. But when I attempt to run it from xcode I'm getting the following:
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue.

Check the name of the Storyboard identifier inside the Identity Inspector and make sure you use the same name.

(A good practice is to use the class name as the identifier)

[image]