# "Unable to open file libc++abi.dylib". Program builds, but crashes upon being run. Using xcode 10.1 (10B61)

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

newbie here. I am following along this SFML flappy bird tutorial. I am currently stuck at this portion of stage creation where a "Splash State" (or logo loading screen) is made. The code of which is *exactly* the same as what is shown [here](https://github.com/SonarSystems/Flappy-Bird-SFML-Clone/tree/master/Code/STATE%20CREATION/7%20-%20Splash%20State).

I am using xcode 10.1.

The project builds. But when I tried running it, it crashes and I am greeted with the following:

> Failed to load image "Resouces/res/Splash Background.png". Reason: Unable to open file
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: map::at:  key not found
>   (lldb)"

If I understand it correctly, it's saying it cannot perform the action of loading the image at the aforementioned path because it is not able to open "libc++abi.dylib". And now the program is being terminated. **(please help me understand this problem better by either confirming or correcting me here)**.

When I tried looking for "libc++abi.dylib", it is missing. Instead, I can only find "libc++abi.td".

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582907/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-sprit) thread says to add that under **Link Binary With Libraries**. That did not produce any result.

The [tutorial](https://youtu.be/elV-DqaYWZo?t=968) shows that the code runs and a "Splash State" or logo screen is expected to appear. Instead my program crashes and I am greeted with the aforementioned error.

I was wondering if anyone else ran into similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. It is made by a typo on my end... sorry.
I'll try my best to explain it here for those of you who may have the same issues:

The game asset is governed by a map, which is a private member variable of a "AssetManager" class. The typo is at the file path. Because of this, the map never inserted the key since the file path isn't valid.

When the map is later accessed, it would be out of range since nothing ever got inserted (since the asset did not load).

Basically, the error of not being to open "libc++abi.dylib" is caused by the map being out of range.